# Create REST API from asynchronous data in Javascript/Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a route that is supposed to be a REST api of metrics I have in a database (they're os usage logs). 
At the moment the api only returns the `json` data headers, like this:

```
{"success":true,"message":"all os logs in database"}
```

The API method

```
const selectOsJSON = () => {
    let os_JSONlogs = { "success":true , "message":"all os logs in database" };
    let arrayLogs = [];

    dbMethods.osModel.findAll( {raw : true, order: [['id', 'DESC']]} ).then( (data) => {
        for(let entry of data)
        {
            arrayLogs.push(entry);
        }
        os_JSONlogs.data = arrayLogs;
        console.log('REST API DATA:', os_JSONlogs);
    } ).catch( (error) => console.log(chalk.redBright('Erreur de promesse REST API OS logs')) ); //need method to adequately shoot the JSON data.

    return os_JSONlogs;
};


module.exports.selectOsJSON = selectOsJSON;
```

The server sample route:

```
app.get('/osjson', (request, response) => { //Should return JSON logs in REST API format

    response.json(apiMethods.selectOsJSON());
    response.end('oslog route - end');

});
```

As you can see the response.json directly adds the data before it can successfully select the records I would like to display.
I have tried using async await with which I have little experience, or creating a new Promise such as `const selectOsJSON = new Promise(//)` with no success.

What I want to achieve is to send the response.json once the data has resolved from the `findAll` query, so I can have a working rest API.
Kindly guide me how to solve it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with a Promise here, so you can definitely use `async` / `await`

```
const selectOsJSON = async () => {
  const os_JSONlogs = { success:true , message:"all os logs in database" };
  try {
    os_JSONlogs.data = await dbMethods.osModel.findAll({
      raw: true,
      order: [['id', 'DESC']]
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // You probably want to catch Mongo-specific errors here
    console.log(chalk.redBright('Erreur de promesse REST API OS logs')) );
    os_JSONlogs.success = false;
    os_JSONlogs.message = 'Erreur de promesse REST API OS logs';
  }
  return os_JSONlogs;
};
```

You can then use the same pattern for the response

```
app.get('/osjson', async (req, res) => {
  const osJson = await apiMethods.selectOsJSON();
  res.json(osJson);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This returns an empty JSON object in the response (without the header) so I think the issue might also come from my server code, which just uses a regular send. I tried using your modified code, and in the server do apiMethods.selectOsJSON().then( (data) => response.json(data) ) but that also didn't display the data

Comment: @aPurpleDev `res.json` is the correct way to return JSON data, when you say "it didn't display the data" in what way? How are you trying to verify the API works?

Comment: I go to the specific route and see which data is displayed on the web page. With this code, it display an empty JSON {}

Comment: @aPurpleDev please show a full working example to demonstrate the problem, that part seems outside the scope of the question but I can help you resolve it if I can see the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

```
const selectOsJSON = async () => {
let os_JSONlogs = { "success":true , "message":"all os logs in database" };
let arrayLogs = [];

const data = await dbMethods.osModel.findAll( {raw : true, order: [['id', 'DESC']]} );
for(let entry of data){
    arrayLogs.push(entry);
}
os_JSONlogs.data = arrayLogs;
console.log('REST API DATA:', os_JSONlogs);

return os_JSONlogs;
};
module.exports.selectOsJSON = selectOsJSON;
```

Please check this code.

Comment: I did, same result: the webpage prints an empty JSON, so I assume it sends the response before getting all the data.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how it got fixed and the API working:

osmetrics.js

```
const selectOsJSON = async () => {
    let os_JSONlogs = { "success":true , "message":"all os logs in database" };
    let arrayLogs = [];

    const data = await dbMethods.osModel.findAll( {raw : true, order: [['id', 'DESC']]} );

    for(let entry of data)
    {
        arrayLogs.push(entry);
    }
    os_JSONlogs.data = arrayLogs;

    return os_JSONlogs;
};

module.exports.selectOsJSON = selectOsJSON;
```

server.js

```
app.get('/osjson', (request, response) => { //Should return JSON logs in REST API format

    apiMethods.selectOsJSON().then( data => {
        response.json(data);
    }).catch( e => console.log(e));

});
```

The catch is optional. The response has the JSON object as intended. Hope it helps someone

Comment: in what way is this different than the answers you received? Unless the answer is completely different then it's not really recommended to use answers given to post your own answer. You should accept the answer that helped you the most, plus your answer isn't reliable at all, it can lead to hanging requests...

Comment: The difference, which is key, is in the server js method that handles the response, this enabled me to make it work and hence is the full solution. Do you think it's helpful?

Comment: the same code you have in the response here is what you commented on my answer that you used and it didn't work. I asked if you could provide an example of the code that isn't working and I could've helped, plus no your answer is confused for various reasons (mixing Promises / async await, unnecessarily iterating your results). See my update, I presume the issue was you just weren't correctly resolving the Promise before sending the response.

Comment: That's right. The fix was mainly to make the method async to be able to use promise behavior to write on the response. I am sorry I didn't fully get your answer if it could have make it work, it didn't. But since you feel so strongly about it I am happy to accept yours as solution. No bad-will here

Comment: no bad-will here either, simply trying to explain the purpose of the site as it would appear you are new.